# Выполнение по очереди

Tags: php

Доброе утро!
Сделал разархивирование архива с помощью php, но после этого нужно получить название файлов и выполнить другое еще действие, но не могу понять как это сделать.

Foreach должен вроде как по очереди выполнять команды и до конца, но хоть и писал, после $gunzip ничего не выполняется.

Это возможно сделать с помощью php? Если да, то подскажите как и, если можно, примером пусть даже легким.

Спасибо

```
$filelist = glob("/emp/*.gz", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($filelist as $key => $value) {
    
    $filename = pathinfo($value);

    $gzname = $filename['basename'];

    $gunzip = shell_exec("gunzip "."/emp/".$gzname);
    
}
```

Comment: Не ясно, что и где не выполняется.

Comment: Язык php, или какой именно вопрос?

Comment: "после $gunzip ничего не выполняется" --- что именно? где конкретно "после"?

Comment: Я понял о чем вы, я писал код после этого но он никак не выполнялся, пример кода

```foreach ($filedirtxt as $keytxt => $valuetxt) {
  
  $filename_txt = pathinfo($valuetxt);

  $name_txt = $filename_txt['basename'];

  echo $name_txt."\n";

 }```

Comment: На начале также задан 
```

$filedirtxt = glob("/emp/*.txt", GLOB_BRACE);

```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: У меня нет никакой ошибки

Comment: Это вы так думаете. Если "он никак не выполнялся" --- значит где-то ошибка. логическая или синтаксическая или ещё какая-либо (да, их не один вид). Для начала надо включить отображение ошибок. А в целом - научиться пользоваться отладкой и посмотреть что происходит на каждой строчке кода. Всё это есть в вопросе-дубликате

Comment: Нет ошибок при выполнении кода.

Comment: И при отладке видно что в каждой строке кода происходит то, что и задумывалось?